# AWS DMS-Oracle to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

Hi what are the steps needed to  migrate my database(Oracle) to AWS using DMS.
 i want to migrate in S3 and then using glue i will migrate it into postgres. 
can anyone suggest step by step process or some link or video which can help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate from Oracle to RDS PostgreSQL the most simple way is to use AWS DMS (Data Migration Services) and the AWS Schema Conversion Tool (AWS SCT).

I will suggest you to take a look at [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/), it will simplify your tasks.

Using S3 and Glue is a lot more complex, you will need to deal with the schema conversion manually, with the datatypes, the loading and so on; that is not the way to handle this task.

I used DMS/SCT several times with great success.

Comment: True, i think even the Stored Procedures can be migrated as well.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo can you suggest me steps or any links or videos how to migrate on premise Oracle data to RDS PostgeSQL.

Comment: Yes, you can use this link from [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2PostgreSQL.html). Best regards